# Wait for Redux props and then do some operations on the props in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a ChatBox component for my website, which displays the chat history of a user. The chat history is not ordered in my firestore, so I want to (1) sort it from the most to the least recent in componentDidMount once I get the data via Redux props (this.props.profile.chats_history) and (2) set the field "chatlist" in the state of ChatBox to the sorted array. The problem is that it takes time for props to be received and when the array.sort() method was called the console reported that the array was undefined. I tried to get around it by using async and await keywords but my solution did not work.

**My solution**

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        let chatlist;
        await this.props.profile.chats_history;
        chatlist = this.props.profile.chats_history.sort(function(a, b) {return a.time - b.time});
        this.setState({
            chatlist: chatlist
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is wait for `chats_history` to be updated, using `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount`. Here I'm doing a deep equal on `this.props.chats_history`.

```
    const _ = require("lodash")
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
          if (!_.isEqual(prevProps.profile.chats_history, this.props.profile.chats_history)) {
              chatlist = this.props.profile.chats_history.sort(function(a, b) {return a.time - b.time});
              this.setState({
                chatlist: chatlist
              })
       }
    }
```

Basically what's happening here is that as soon as the component mounts, `this.props.chats_history` will have some value, but it won't contain the actual list of values yet. At some point, `this.props.chats_history` will be loaded, and this will trigger the component to update.

`componentDidUpdate` is triggered every time either `this.props` or `this.state` is updated. The arguments `prevProps` and `prevState` that you see in my code are references to the values of `this.props` and `this.state` from immediately before the update occurred that triggered `componentDidUpdate`.

`componentDidUpdate` will be triggered many times, and you want to execute your `sort` function only when it's the loading of `this.props.chats_history` that has triggered it. To do this, you compare (with `_.isEqual`) `prevProps.chats_history` with `this.props.chats_history`. Is they're *not* equal, this means that `this.props.chats_history` was just modified (in this case, loaded), so you call `sort` only under these circumstances.

The reason I use `_.isEqual` from the `lodash` library is that if I did a `==` or `===` comparison, it would always return `true` because `this.props.chats_history` is an array, and it would therefore be comparing the references rather than the contents of the array. If you use `_.isEqual` it does a deep comparison and returns `true` only if each element of `this.props.chats_history` is equal to each element of `prevProps.chats_history`.

Since you then call `this.setState()`, `componentDidUpdate` will be called again, but the `if` block will return `false` and not run the `sort` code again.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and detailed explanation! Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getDerivedStateFromProps instead.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const sortedChat = props.profile.chats_history?[...props.profile.chats_history].sort((a,b)=>{/*logic*/}):[]
    return { sortedChat };
}
```

You can optimize your renders by comparing the current data in state and received data in props. That depends on your data again. Personally, I'd keep a timestamp in profile.chats and only update the state when timestamp changes. Also, sort changes the original array order. So, clone before you sort like I did above.